# Edges for the union (overlaped) of multiple 3d objects. Using EdgeForm and RegionUnion

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions, rendering

I'm trying to generate **outer edges** of two **overlapping** **objects**. I've thought that one can overlap objects with RegionUnion. However I don't want to get the inner edges to be drawn.

I tried the EdgeForm[] function, but couldn't manage to just generate the outer edges of the overlapping objects.

This is my attempt:

```
Graphics3D[
 {
  {Blue // Lighter // Lighter, Opacity[0.8]
   , RegionUnion[
    Parallelepiped[{-.25, -.5, 0}, {{.5, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -0.04}}]
    , Parallelepiped[{-.5, -.25, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, .5, 0}, {0, 0, -0.04} }]
    ]
   }
  , {Gray, Opacity[0.2], EdgeForm[],
   RegionUnion[
    Parallelepiped[{-.25, -.5, -0.04}, {{.5, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0,  0, -0.08}}]
    , Parallelepiped[{-.5, -.25, -0.04}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, .5, 0}, {0, 0, -0.08}}]
    ]}}]
```

[image]

Any suggestion? Thanks for reading

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`` Region`Mesh`MergeCells ``

```
solids = {Parallelepiped[{-.25, -.5, 
     0}, {{.5, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -0.04}}], 
   Parallelepiped[{-.5, -.25, 
     0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, .5, 0}, {0, 0, -0.04}}], 
   Parallelepiped[{-.25, -.5, -0.04}, {{.5, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 
      0, -0.08}}], 
   Parallelepiped[{-.5, -.25, -0.04}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, .5, 0}, {0, 
      0, -0.08}}]};
mesh = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion[solids]] // 
   Region`Mesh`MergeCells;
Graphics3D[{Blue // Lighter // Lighter, Opacity[0.8], mesh}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

One way by using the `RegionPlot3D` after converting the polyhedron(`RegionUnion[..]`) to `Region`.

```
solids = {Parallelepiped[{-.25, -.5, 0}, {{.5, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -0.04}}], 
Parallelepiped[{-.5, -.25, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, .5, 0}, {0, 0, -0.04}}], 
Parallelepiped[{-.25, -.5, -0.04}, {{.5, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -0.08}}], 
Parallelepiped[{-.5, -.25, -0.04}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, .5, 0}, {0, 0, -0.08}}]};

RegionPlot3D[{Region@RegionUnion[solids]},PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue // Lighter // Lighter, Opacity[0.8]]]
```

[image]

Comment: I really like the rendering of this one, than the Graphics3D function. However as I'm working with more Graphic3D objects (text callouts, arrows, etc), the RegionPlot3D is uncompatible with my objects. (maybe i'm not constructing them properly) Thanks! How can I get this rendering for the Graphic3D function?

Comment: The RegionPlot3D returns Graphics3D as a head, therefore you can combine it with other Graphics3D objects by using the Show function or you can use it together with other objects inside a single Graphics3D call by removing the Graphics3D head e.g. 
Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, .05, 0}, .1], 
 List @@ RegionPlot3D[{Region@RegionUnion[solids]}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue // Lighter // Lighter, Opacity[0.8]]]}]